# PostgresSQL - Stored procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql

O que há de errado nesta Stored Procedure?

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sp_teste
(
  IN           varchar,
  OUT  codigo  integer,
  OUT  setor   varchar,
  OUT  grupo   integer
)
RETURNS SETOF record AS
$$
begin   
  return query SELECT codigo, setor, grupo FROM vw_setor WHERE vw_setor.setor LIKE $1;   
end;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100;

ALTER FUNCTION public.sp_teste(varchar)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Está retornando este erro:

```
SQL Error: ERROR:  column "smt" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM public.sp_teste(smt) LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0
                                      ^
```

Observação: "SMT" é o parâmetro para busca.

Comment: De onde vem o parâmetro?

Answer (score 1):

Você deve chamar a sua função com todas as informações que você solicita como parâmetros.
No caso do parâmetro smt use aspas simples já que sua função esta solicitando um varchar.

```
SELECT * FROM public.sp_teste('smt') LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0
```